# Querying XSLT returning names filtered for "stan"

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:template match="country[@name]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="country=[*stan"]" >
    </xsl:if> </xsl:template>
```

Can somebody please tell me where I go wrong with this query. I'm supposed to return only the names of countries with "stan" in them (Turkmenistan, etc). The XML data includes country/area, name, population.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong in your code:

1. The XPath expression on the if statement, which is wrong because it
   does not follow the syntax of XPath. If you want to check in the if
   statement whether the name of the country contains stan then the
   XPath expression should be:

   ```
    country[contains(@name, 'stan')]
   ```
2. Even with that correction the stylesheet would not match country names
   containing 'stan' in it, because the match expression is matching all
   countries which have a name attribute (country[@name]) and then you are
   outputting the country name using value-of inside the template.

A solution for fixing your code would be changing the value-of element into
the if element, and changing the XPath expression from the one that I specified
before.

However, it is much simpler to match the condition before entering the template.
So the solution would be:

```
<xsl:template match="country[contains(@name, 'stan')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
</xsl:template>
```